# Classic ASP formatnumber error

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to classic asp and so I am trying to understand the below code which is causing an error

```
<input class="uploadCalcField" type="text"  size="12" name="<%="upload" & "z" & rs("e_cat_id") & "z" & l2_id & "z" & l1_id%>" value="<%=formatnumber(Request.Form("upload" & "z" & rs("e_cat_id") & "z" & l2_id & "z" & l1_id), 0)%>" onClick="this.blur();">
```

the error is

> type mismatch: 'formatnumber'.

I have checked the output of

```
Request.Form("upload" & "z" & rs("e_cat_id") & "z" & l2_id & "z" & l1_id)
```

and it's empty which seems to be the cause, can anybody help me to understand the error?

Comment: Normally that kind of error means something like there is no actual number to format. Have you tried debugging the value of the number you are trying to feed into formatnumber(), so you can see what values you are or aren't working with?

Comment: For example, you are entering a big long list of values into formatnumber, and also, you seem to be including a "z" a few times - that alone will break formatnumber, since it's not a number.

Comment: @Idiot, in fact I am also thinking the same. As this is legacy code, wondering for what reason code is written like that. But at this minute I am totally puzzled :(

Comment: @Idiot Actually the whole `z`  stuff is part of the `Request.Form()` call inside the `FormatNumber()` at the moment it's looking for `"upload" & "z" & rs("e_cat_id") & "z" & l2_id & "z" & l1_id` in the `Request.Form()` collection and not finding it. Try outputting just the string `"upload" & "z" & rs("e_cat_id") & "z" & l2_id & "z" & l1_id` what does it generate?, whatever it is it isn't being found in the `Request.Form()` collection.

Comment: @Lankymart, can you tell me what is "upload" here is it function? or some event

Comment: It's just a string made up of various variables, if you output it with `Response.Write()` you will be able to see what it's true value is. When you post a HTML `<form>` to a Classic ASP page it takes the form elements passed *(by name)* and creates a key-value pair string that it passes to the Classic ASP for processing *(basic HTML POST)*. Classic ASP then parses that string and builds a collection the `Request.Form()` collection, you can pass it keys to access various values that were passed with the POST.

Comment: @Lankymart, you mean Request.Form() or Request.Form("upload" & "z" & rs("e_cat_id") & "z" & l2_id & "z" & l1_id)

Comment: Write this line somewhere above where the line that errors... `Call Response.Write("upload" & "z" & rs("e_cat_id") & "z" & l2_id & "z" & l1_id)`whats the result?

Comment: its uploadz10101z10100z10000.

Comment: So the value `uploadz10101z10100z10000` does not exist as a key in the `Request.Forms()` collection, that is the problem. You can test that like this `Call Response.Write(Request.Form("uploadz10101z10100z10000"))`. If you right click the generated HTML page in your Browser and View the Source what is the `name` attribute of the `<input class="uploadCalcField"` tag set to? Is it `uploadz10101z10100z10000` or something else?

Comment: @Lankymart, thank you for your help. I am checking the Form collection to identify why respective value is not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FormatNumber()` fails because as you point out in the question the value it is trying to format that comes from `Request.Form()` is empty.

The `Request.Form` collection is built by Classic ASP when a HTML form is submitted to Classic ASP using the `POST` `method`.

Here is a simple example

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Form Submission to Classic ASP</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="/test.asp">
      <input type="text" name="testinput" value="hello world" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the `Submit Form` button is pressed in the Browser a HTTP request is generated and sent off to the Web Server, in this case to Classic ASP to process.

```
POST http://example.com/test.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

testinput=hello%20world
```

*<sup>*More headers would be passed but removed to keep the example simple</sup>*

Classic ASP takes the string of key-value pairs and populates the `Request.Form` collection

test.asp *(called when `Submit Form` button is pressed in HTML page)*

```vb
<%
Call Response.Write(Request.Form("testinput"))
%>
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

Comment: Thank you for yo help :)